# Application not defined when trying to set variable through console

Tags: vue.js

Getting my feet wet in Vue:

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  Vue.component('coordinate-form', {
    template: `<form><input type="text" v-model:"coord"></input><input type="submit"></input></form>`
  });

  const app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#findcoordinate',
    data: {
      coord: '000 000'
    }
  });
console.log(app.coord); -- prints 000 000 in console.

});
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="findcoordinate">
    <coordinate-form></coordinate-form>
  </div>
```

When when I do in the console:

```
app.coord = "Something";
```

I get:

```
VM1674:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `app` inside function for `DOMContentLoad` event so it inaccessible outside it (also in console). You need to define `app` variable in window object to access it globally:

```js
const app = new Vue({
   ///...
});

window.app = app;
```